# Inserción de datos en una base de datos access en java

Tags: java, ms-access

Buenas estoy comenzando a programar en java y quiero insertar datos en una base de datos de access mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
class conexion {

public  Statement stm;
private  Connection conexion;
private  ResultSet rst;

public conexion(String ins) {
    try {
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://src/base_datos/aplicativo.mdb");
        stm = conexion.createStatement();
        rst = stm.executeQuery(ins);
        System.out.println("CONEXION REALIZADA CON EXITO");
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.out.println("ERROR AL CONECTARSE A LA BASE DE DATOS"+sql);
    }

}
```

}
Instancio la clase conexion y le envio el parametro con la instruccion sql

```
String ins = ("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES " + cedula + "," + JTnombre.getText() + "," + JTapellidos.getText() + "," + JTresidencia.getText() +"");
            conexion datos = new conexion(ins);
```

Pero me bota el siguiente error:

```
ERROR AL CONECTARSE A LA BASE DE DATOSnet.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 palabra no esperado: ,
```

Me podrían ayudar a solucionarlo porque se da, les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Parece que se ha colado una "," (coma) en tu sentencia sql. Verifíca que la consulta sea correcta. Que contiene JTnombre, JTapellidos y JTresidencia? Por otro lado, la tabla usuarios sólo contiene esas 4 columnas?

Comment: Efectivamente tiene solo esas cuatro columnas y si tengo todos los campos en mi JFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de investigar por casi toda la red encontre mi error lo que sucedia era que al usar:

```
rst = stm.executeQuery(ins);
```

Hacia referencia a una consulta o extraccion de datos de la bd no se lo usa para todo lo que tenga que ver en una actualizacion de la db ya sea INSERT, UPDATE O DELETE en mi caso:

```
try {
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://src/base_datos/aplicativo.mdb");
            PreparedStatement pstm = conexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuarios(cedula,nombres,apellidos,residencia) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
            pstm.setInt(1,cedula);
            pstm.setString(2, JTnombre.getText());
            pstm.setString(3,JTapellidos.getText());
            pstm.setString(4,JTresidencia.getText());
            pstm.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch(SQLException error)
                   {
                   System.out.println(error);
                   }
        }
```

Esta fue la solución usar el PreparedStatement();.

GRACIAS A TODOS POR SUS APORTES APRENDÍ ALGO NUEVO SOBRE EL USO DE LAS COMILLAS EN LAS CONSULTAS.

Answer (score 2):

La sentencia SQL tiene error de sintaxis. Te faltan las comillas simples para delimitar los VALUES. El error marca que ha encontrado una coma (,) inesperada.

La estás mandando del siguiente modo:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios
VALUES (Cardinal, Stavanger, Norway);
```

Y tendría que ser así:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');
```

Comment: No entendi esa parte lo de las comillas simples si le pongo comilla simples me lo toma como cadena de texto y no como variables.

Comment: Recoge la variable y después pones las comillas: `String ins = 
("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES '" + cedula + "','" + JTnombre.getText() + "','" + JTapellidos.getText() + "','" + JTresidencia.getText() + "'""");`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores en la sintaxis de la sentencia SQL. Te faltan las comillas simples para cada valor, como ya lo mencionaron anteriormente pero también los paréntesis está mal. La consulta debe ser similar a esta:

```
String ins = ("INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES ('" + cedula + "','" + JTnombre.getText() + "','" + JTapellidos.getText() + "','" + JTresidencia.getText() +"')";
            conexion datos = new conexion(ins);
```

Comment: Lo hice pero ahora me marca este error:[ ERROR AL CONECTARSE A LA BASE DE DATOSnet.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 excepción de datos: valor incorrecto para CAST]